# Python connecting to MySQL database name error

Tags: python, mysql

I got the following code from this site to connect to a mysql database through python (which is much appreciated by the way). I have used it once already to connect to a database on the server, but in a different file. However I know want to connect to another database on the same server but i keep getting error message to do with the database name. 
I am using exactly the same code as I was before to connect, however i have only changed the database name to the other one i want to connect to. I can look at the database through puTTY, and see that it is called the correct name and that all the data is there, but just cant seem to connect properly through the Python.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
  #!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="........", # your password
                      db="opt_out") # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the query you need
cur = db.cursor() 

# Use all the SQL you like
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM opted_in")

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in cur.fetchall() :
    print row[0]
```

And this is the error code i get in return when i try and execute the python file through puTTY:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/vra/ConnectAdiDB.py", line 7, in <module>
    db="opt_out") # name of the data base
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

Comment: The error message doesn't say anything about the database name. You get that error if the username or password are incorrect, or the user doesn't have access to the selected database.

Comment: What does `show grants for root@localhost` show?

Comment: Most likely the user doesn't have any access to the database. Try to use `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES`

Comment: Here is some `mysql` syntax for granting privileges: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON [database_name].* TO '[username]'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY '[password]' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I see i didn't know it was an privilege error. I have typed the following code in the puTTy to try and grant access, however it keeps responding that no database is selected:GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON opt_out TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '........' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
mysql>

Comment: Try ```use opt_out``` (or whatever the name of the DB is) first then repeat the ```GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES...``` command.

Answer (score 0):

The Password must be wrong (I Think so)

So Try to reset the password so:
first off turn of the mysql Service like so

Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

After That Do So:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

When Done Start mysql like so:

```
sudo mysql
```

An execute:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('NEW-PASSWORD') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```